# Problem of the month. Thinking problem?

Tags: problem-solving

Cherise scored 85 on her last math exam of 100 questions.  Her teacher has an unusual way of scoring this test.  He calculated her score by subtracting 2 times the number of wrong answers from the number of correct answers.  If Cherise answered all 100 questions, how many did she get correct?

Comment: Let $x$ be the number of correct answers.  Can you form an equation to get $85$?

Comment: Still kinda confused with what equation should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

score = correct - 2*(wrong)

85 = c-2w

but we have c+w=100 so, c=100-w and therefore;

85=100-w-2w

-15=-3w

w=5

Cherise answered 5 questions with the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  if she got $x$ correct, what was her score?

Answer (score 0):

$x =$ # of wrong answers, $y =$ # of correct answers $\implies y - 2x = 85$, and $x + y = 100$. So 
$$y - 2(100 - y) = 85 \implies 3y = 285 \implies y = 285/3 = 95$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the number of correct answers be $x$. Then the number of incorrect answers is $100 - x$. Thus,

$$x - 2(100 - x) = 85$$

Manipulate and solve directly for $x$, i.e. the number of correct answers.